# Trouble formatting a sequence

Tags: formatting, amsmath, sequence

I'm trying to type this problem but I'm having issues as to how I go about the bit within the braces on the right side of the equals sign.

[image]

Here's my attempt at formatting this question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
\left\{a_t\right\}_{t=1}^4 \text{ defined recursively by } a_t=
\left\{(x,y)\Bigg|
\begin{cases}
x=t \\
y=9-t^2
\end{cases}
\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to TeX-SE. Try to fit your cases into a `matrix` environment, like in the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
\left\{a_t\right\}_{t=1}^4 \text{ defined recursively by } a_t=
\left\{(x,y)\Bigg|\, 
\begin{matrix}
x=t \\
y=9-t^2
\end{matrix}
\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: sequence]

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `array`. I present also the version without the inner brace, which I find unnecessary, and my preferred one at the bottom with a single line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
\{a_t\}_{t=1}^4
\text{ defined recursively by }
a_t=
\left\{(x,y)\;\middle|\;
\left\{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
x=t \\
y=9-t^2
\end{array}\right.
\vphantom{\Bigg|}
\right\}
\]

\[
\{a_t\}_{t=1}^4
\text{ defined recursively by }
a_t=
\left\{(x,y)\;\middle|\;
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
x=t \\
y=9-t^2
\end{array}
\right\}
\]

\[
\{a_t\}_{t=1}^4 \text{ defined recursively by }
a_t=\{(x,y) \mid x=t, y=9-t^2 \}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I propose this simple code, using an `aligned` environment, and the `\set` command, as defined by the `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]\{\}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{\nonscript\,#1\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\allowbreak #2\nonscript\,}}

\begin{document}

\[
\set{a_t}_{t=1}^4 \text{ defined recursively by } a_t=
\set[\bigg]{(x,y);
\begin{aligned}
x & =t \\[-0.5ex]
y & =9-t^2
\end{aligned}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]